# Python - How to do unit testing of functions deleting something?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have two functions, one creates an object and store in list call `create()`, the other deletes object form list call `delete()`.

I have already written unit test using unittest module for `create()`.
But I have no idea how to write unit test for `delete()`.

Because of `delete()` depends on `create()`.
It is impossible to delete object before create it.

If I write unit test for `delete()` by calling `create()` first.
When test fail, I don't know which function cause test fail.

```
def create(self, clusterName):
    import uuid

    newClusterUuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    newCluster = Cluster(uuid = newClusterUuid, name = clusterName)
    self.clusterList[newClusterUuid] = newCluster
    return newClusterUuid

def delete(self, uuid):
    try:
        del self.clusterList[uuid]
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Can you share your code so we have something concrete to reference?

Comment: If `create()` fails, the unit test for `create()` should fail too. So, you fix `create()`, then if `delete()` still fails, you know you need to fix `delete()`.

Comment: @Mureinik OK! But my code is too long, I simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods too. So you would put the `create()` in setup, and if it fails, your `delete()` test will automatically be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

In testing, you have "expected failures" that are actually proof that your function is working.

So for your delete function, you might test all of these scenarios:

1. It raises an exception when there is nothing to delete (ie, nothing has been created).
2. If it does delete, the total is reduced.
3. It checks that the amount to be delete is less than the total amount of things.

In case #1, you expect it to fail - and if it does fail (it raises the exception) - it actually passes the test.

There are also ways to mark a test as [expected failure](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.expectedFailure); which basically means that if this test fails to run, then its not a failure.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I design my test case according to your suggestion. And I use the setup and tearDown methods to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate delete and create by initializing a fake clusterlist.

```
#setup
fakeClusterList = [1,3,5,6,0]
fakeUUID = 3

# test delete with your delete method
```

A better way would be to inject Cluster into your create method (i.e. pass it in as a parameter). In this way, you can pass in a mock Cluster object which would return a fake list for testing.

There would thus be a much lower likelihood of the fake `create` failing during unit testing of `delete` since the actual create logic (which might be complicated) is gotten rid of.

Do read up on [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).